# How to add JavaFX Preloader ProgressBar on top of an FXML scene

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am new to Java and JavaFX all together, so please be patient with me if I am asking the wrong question here.

I am trying to add preloader Scene to an application I built: I was able to add the preloader using the code below. It's the default preloader and it looks very basic. So, here is my question. 1) how to add percentage progress status instead of progressbar. 2) Is it possible to load this progress bar on top of an FXML scene

```
Preloader

public class JavaFXPreloader3 extends Preloader {

    ProgressBar bar;
    Stage stage;

private Scene createPreloaderScene() throws IOException {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml"));

    ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
    BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
    p.setCenter(pi);
    return new Scene(p, 300, 150);

}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.stage = stage;
        stage.setScene(createPreloaderScene());        
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleStateChangeNotification(StateChangeNotification scn) {
        if (scn.getType() == StateChangeNotification.Type.BEFORE_START) {
            stage.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleProgressNotification(ProgressNotification pn) {
        bar.setProgress(pn.getProgress());
    }    

}
```

How do I return root scene instead of  the BorderPane p including the Progress Indicator:

```
 ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
    BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
    p.setCenter(pi);
    return new Scene(p, 300, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a excellent tutorial for creating a PreLoader.

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm